# Converting SDE to ODE via Dynkin's formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm reading on Dynkin's formula. Given a stationary diffusion process $X(t)$ in the form
$$dX(t) = \mu(X(t))dt +\sigma(X(t))dW$$
, as a generalization of the 2nd fundamental theorem of Calculus $F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^b f(x)dx$, we have Dynkin's formula
$$\mathbb E^{X(t)=x}f(X(T))=f(x) + \mathbb E^{X(t)=x} \int_t^T \mathscr Lf(X(s)) ds$$
, where $\mathscr L$ is the infinitesimal generator of $X(t)$, ie
$\mathscr L = \mu \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac12 \sigma^2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$.

So far so good.

But then I came into this [A celebration of Dynkin’s formula](http://lipas.uwasa.fi/%7Etsottine/talks/Changsha2015-HFNU.pdf) slides of Prof. [Tommi Sottinen](http://www.uva.fi/%E2%88%BCtsottine/). It gives an application of Dynkin's formula, which got me totally lost --

> Consider the 2nd order ordinary differential equations (ODE) on
> $u(x)$: $$\mu(x)u'(x)+\frac12 \sigma^2(x) u''(x) = 0, \qquad x\in
> (a,b)\subset \mathbb R$$
> with boundary conditions $u(a)$ and $u(b)$.
> Let $X$ be the Ito diffusion $$dX=\mu(X) dt+\sigma(X) dW$$ It follows
> from the Dynkin's formula that $$u(x)=\mathbb E^x u(X(\tau))$$ , where
> $\tau$ is the first exit time of $X$ from the interval $(a,b)$.

I really couldn't understand this SDE->ODE convertion. Why does it work?

So far my trying to understand it is --

The ODE $\mu(x)u'(x)+\frac12 \sigma^2(x) u''(x) = 0$ is just $$\mathscr Lu(x)=0$$
Substitue with $u(x)=\mathbb E^x u(X(\tau))$ we get
$$\mathscr L \mathbb E^x u(X(t)) = 0$$
, which is equivalent to
$$\mathbb E^x \mathscr L u(X(t)) = 0$$
, which means $\mathscr Lu(X(t))$ is a martingale.

But how can this be derived from Dynkin's formula?

Comment: More details with proofs can be found in the book by Karatzas & Shreve, *Brownian Motion an Stochastic Calculus*. They have a whole chapter on the relationship between PDEs and SDEs. The subject is too broad and to well-known to be repeated in MSE based on a few slides however nice they might be.

Comment: @KurtG. thanks for the tip. Actually I had the book, but it's a bit too deep for me so so far it's just collecting dust. The chapter you referred to, is it Ch 4 *Brownian motion and Partial Differential Equations*?

Comment: This is it obviously. You will probably have to read more than that to understand what they do.

Comment: I am not sure to see where the question starts or finishes but if you apply Dynkin's formula with the knowledge of the ODE $\mu(x)u'(x)+\frac12 \sigma^2(x) u''(x) = 0$, with $f=u$ we get $$\mathbb E^{X(t)=x}u(X(T))=u(x) + \mathbb E^{X(t)=x} \int_t^T \mathscr Lu(X(s)) ds=u(x) + \mathbb E^{X(t)=x} \int_t^T 0  ds =u(x)$$, there is nothing more to it. Now  if you read the proof of Dynkin formula you will apply Itô then take expectation and by the conditions of theorem get the diffusion term to be 0 and that's because ! the diffusion term is a martingale and not the other way around.

Comment: @TheBridge thanks! I think you are right, thanks for the tip! the rest would be how the stopping time comes into playing. hopefully i'll read the book as Kurt suggested and answer the question one day.